# Linking User Type To Data In Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm working with linking a user type to a particular field in google analytics. For example, if I want to know the top search words from the user type "Customers", I'm creating a custom report in GA and adding in the fields like search word along with the custom dimension (user-type). But the search word is not being linked to a particular user type.

Is there any way of knowing that a search word came in from this user type ? Does google do that internally or do we have to some how link which search words came from which user types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the User type is a dimension in the reports, you can use a **new segment** in the **Overview** of **Site Search** and use a **Condition** that includes in the report only the type "Costumers".
The report with this filter will only show data, as search term, from these specific type of user. 
Hope I've helpd.

Comment: Thanks Blanca, I've included a filter that includes only a specific User Type and I'm now able to get the top search words from that User Type.